# Communication between Arduino and Python via UDP

Tags: python, arduino, udp

I am struggling to build a communication bridge between Arduino and Python. Arduino should send an integer value to python. To enable the Udp communication I am using Ethernet shield 2 on Arduino and have to connect to IP "192.168.137.30". 
Now when I try to connect to bind with this Ip address, an error occurs because "192.168.137.30" is an external Ip address.

Below is my Arduino and python code :

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <Ethernet2.h>
#include <EthernetUdp2.h>         // UDP library from: bjoern@cs.stanford.edu 12/30/2008

byte mac[] = {
  0xA8, 0x61, 0x0A, 0xAE, 0x2A, 0x12
};
IPAddress ip(192.168.137.30);

unsigned int localPort = 8880;      // local port to listen on

// An EthernetUDP instance to let us send and receive packets over UDP
EthernetUDP Udp;


void setup()
{


  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  Udp.begin(localPort);
  Serial.begin(115200);

  }

void loop()
{

   char  ReplyBuffer[] = "acknowledged";    
    Udp.beginPacket(ip, localPort);
    Udp.write(ReplyBuffer);
    Udp.endPacket();

}
```

Python :

```
import serial
import time 
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('192.168.137.30', 8880))
data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
sock.close()
```

---

I still can not send data from Arduino to Python. However, it is possible to send data from Python to Arduino.

```
IPAddress ip(169, 254, 114, 130);
IPAddress my_PC_ip(169, 254, 94, 133);
unsigned int localPort = 7476; 
unsigned int pythonPort= 7000; 

void setup()
{
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  Udp.begin(localPort);
  Serial.begin(115200);

  }

void loop()
{
    Udp.beginPacket(my_PC_ip,pythonPort);
    Udp.print("hello");
    Udp.endPacket();
}
```

Python :
    import serial
    import time 
    import socket

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('169.254.94.133', 7000))
data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
sock.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not putting the right IP addresses in the right places. Here's what should be where:

- In `Ethernet.begin` on the Arduino, you should use the Arduino's IP address.
- In `Udp.beginPacket` on the Arduino, you should use your computer's IP address.
- In `sock.bind` on your computer, you should use your computer's IP address.

You're currently using the same one in all three places, which doesn't make sense from a networking perspective.

Comment: Do you mean with the computer's IP address the localhost 127.0.0.1 or the Ethernet-Adapter IPv4 Adress or the WLAN-Adapter WLAN IPv4 Address?

Comment: @Joe Does the computer use Ethernet or WLAN to connect to the network that the Arduino is on? Use that one. (Definitely not localhost.)

Comment: Actually "192.168.137.30" is used to be connected with Arduino via Ethernet. So "192.168.137.30" should be the computer's IP address and in the same time Arduino's IP address ? But the problem is that I cant bind to this external IP address in python....

Comment: Ok, this  "192.168.137.30" is the static Ip address that I manually signed to Arduino. Since the connection to Arduino happens via Ethernet, this static Ip address is now the Ip address of my Ethernet. Due to this reason  "192.168.137.30" is my Arduino's IP address and my computer's Ethernet address at the same time. Is there a way around here?

Comment: You configured them wrong. Just give them different IP addresses.

Comment: Yes I gave Arduino another IP address as I edited above. However the python script still can not receive anything....